# How can I programmatically make methods chainable?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a class and I want to make its methods chainable, I could do something like this:

```
class MyClass {

  def methodOne(arg1: Any): MyClass = {
    println("doing stuff")
    this
  }

  def methodTwo(arg1: Any, arg2: Any): MyClass = {
    println("doing other stuff")
    this
  }
}
```

While that would achieve the functionality I'm looking for, it's not very elegant in my opinion. Is there a better way of doing this?

Assuming it's possible, I'd like to be able to do something like the following, but I'm not sure how to approach the `makeChainable` function.

```
class MyClass {

  val methodOne: Any => MyClass = 
    makeChainable((arg1: Any) => println("doing stuff"))

  val methodTwo: (Any, Any) => MyClass = 
    makeChainable((arg1: Any, arg2: Any) => println("doing other stuff"))

}
```

Comment: I recommend you not call functions methods. (Most often, people make the reverse mistake, calling methods functions.) The two `val` you define, `methodOne` and `methodTwo` are of type `Function1` and `Function2`, resp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option is the most efficient one, the other one introduces overhead by wrapping code into function object. But it's certainly possible to create such a wrapper. Let's define

```
trait Chainable {
  final def mkChain(f: () => Any): () => this.type =
    () => { f(); this; }
  final def mkChain[A](f: (A) => Any): (A) => this.type =
    (x: A) => { f(x); this; }
  final def mkChain[A,B](f: (A,B) => Any): (A,B) => this.type =
    (x: A, y: B) => { f(x, y); this; }
  // etc. for other arities
}
```

Notice `this.type`, it says the result of our functions is the type of the class they're defined in. So now when we mix it into our class

```
class MyClass extends Chainable {
  val methodTwo =
    mkChain((x: Any, y: String) => println("Doing something " + y));
}
```

the result of `methodTwo` will be `MyClass`.

---

**Update:** There is another option, to use implicit conversions:

```
trait ToChain {
  implicit class AsThis(val _underlying: Any) {
    def chain: ToChain.this.type = ToChain.this
  }
}

class MyClass2 extends ToChain {
  def methodOne(arg1: Any): Unit =
    println("Doing something")
  def methodTwo(arg1: String): Unit =
    println("Doing something else " + arg1)

  methodOne(3).chain.methodTwo("x");
}
```

Calling `chain` converts anything to `this.type`. However it only works inside the class, you can't call something like `new MyClass2.methodOne(3).chain.methodTwo("x")` outside.

---

**Update:** Yet another solution, based on implicit conversion from `Unit` to `this`:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class Chain[A](val x: A) {
  implicit def unitToThis(unit: Unit): A = x;
}
implicit def unchain[A](c: Chain[A]): A = c.x;

// Usage:

val r: MyClass = new Chain(new MyClass) {
  x.methodOne(1).methodTwo(2,3);
}
```

Comment: Why is that only available within the class? Importing the implicit inner class in some outer scope doesn't have the same effect?

Comment: @DaoWen Yes, it works, but it isn't as flexible. If you use imports, you can do something similar to chaining by importing a value like `val x = new MyClass; { import x._; methodOne(..); methodTwo(..); }` without wrapping anything etc.

Comment: I saw that method in the thread on `doto`, but that wasn't what I was talking about. I was wondering what's preventing me from doing `import myClass2Instance.AsThis` or something like that to get the chaining behavior outside the class.

Comment: @DaoWen You're right, you can do something like `val x = new MyClass2; import x._; methodOne(1).chain.methodTwo("x");`. What I meant is that if you import `x._` then I feel it's simpler to split the calls into separate statements rather than to `chain` them. But of course it depends on your preferences.

Comment: That makes sense. I just don't like the idea of using `x._` because you import the _entire_ set of members, and some of the names might inadvertently conflict with names you wanted to use as arguments. But, that answers my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to implement `makeChainable` for unary function, but it gets hairy if you want to support higher arity. The only way I can see to do method two, unless you want to write a separate `makeChainable` for every arity, is to tuple the method, pass it through `makeChainable`, and then untuple it.

```
class MyClass {

  def methodOne: Any => MyClass = makeChainable {
    (arg1: Any) => println("doing stuff")
  }

  def methodTwo: (Any, Any) => MyClass = Function untupled makeChainable {(
    (arg1: Any, arg2: Any) => println("doing other stuff")
  ).tupled}

  def makeChainable[A](f: (A) => Unit): (A => MyClass) = { a: A => f(a); this }

}

new MyClass().methodOne("a").methodTwo("b", "c")
```

But - and please forgive me for opining - invocation chaining is generally a shortcut you take in other languages that are less expressive than Scala. Unless you're doing this to make an API for Java users, I think this is a really bad idea.

Here's one alternative, which I still would never do, to accomplish roughly the style you're going for in a way that's less invasive:

```
class MyClass {
  def methodOne(a: Any) { println("doing stuff") }
  def methodTwo(a: Any, b: Any) { println("doing other stuff") }
  def apply(fs: (MyClass => Unit)*) { fs.foreach(f => f(this)) }
}

new MyClass()(_.methodOne("a"), _.methodTwo("b", "c"))
```

Edit:

A more elegant way would be to define a "kestrel combinator". I do think this approach is legit :)

```
class MyClass {
  def methodOne(a: Any) { println("doing stuff") }
  def methodTwo(a: Any, b: Any) { println("doing other stuff") }
}

implicit class Kestrel[A](x: A) {
  def ~(f: A => Unit): A = { f(x); x }
}

new MyClass() ~ (_.methodOne("a")) ~ (_.methodTwo("b", "c"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't probably exactly what you're looking for, but your description reminds me a lot of the [`doto` construct in Clojure](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doto).

I found a couple of threads discussing the different ways of porting `doto` to Scala:

[something like Clojure's "doto"?](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2492)

[Re: something like Clojure's "doto"?](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2599) (I think this was actually a reply to the first thread that somehow ended up as a separate thread)

Looking through those threads, it looks like the easiest way is just to make a `val` with a short name and use that as the receiver of repeated statements.

Or create an implicit value class (available in Scala 2.10):

```
implicit class Doto[A](val value: A) extends AnyVal {
  def doto(statements: (A => Any)*): A = {
    statements.foreach((f: A => Any) => f(value))
    value
  }
}
new MyClass2().doto(_.methodOne(3), _.methodTwo("x"));
```

The other answers are much more what you're looking for, but I just wanted to point out an alternate approach another language took for working around non-chainable method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the question of how wise this is in the first place, it's pretty easy to implement in a type-safe and boilerplate-free way with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

```
import shapeless._

trait ChainableUtils {
  def makeChainable[F, Args <: HList](f: F)(implicit
    in: FnHListerAux[F, Args => Unit],
    out: FnUnHLister[Args => this.type]
  ) = out((a: Args) => { in(f)(a); this })
}
```

And then:

```
scala> class MyClass extends ChainableUtils {
     |   def func1 = makeChainable((i: Int) => println("Doing stuff."))
     |   def func2 = makeChainable((a: Any, b: Any) => 
     |     println("Doing other stuff."))
     | }
defined class MyClass

scala> val myInstance = new MyClass
myInstance: MyClass = MyClass@6c86b570

scala> myInstance.func1(1).func2('a, "a").func1(42)
Doing stuff.
Doing other stuff.
Doing stuff.
res0: myInstance.type = MyClass@6c86b570
```

This will work for any `FunctionN`.