# Is there an easy way to chain java setters that are void instead of return this

Tags: scala

I have a bunch of auto-generated java code that I will be calling in scala.  Currently all of the objects were generated with void setters instead of returning `this` which makes it really annoying when you need to set a bunch of values (I'm not going to use the constructor by initializing everything since there's like 50 fields).  For example:

```
val o = new Obj()
o.setA("a")
o.setB("b")
o.setC("c")
```

It would be really cool if I could do something like this

```
val o = with(new Obj()) {
  _.setA("a")
  _.setB("b")
  _.setC("c")
}
```

I can't use andThen with anon functions since they require objects to be returned.  Am I stuck with the current way I'm doing things or is there some magic I'm not aware of.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17692536/1333025

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use `tap` (the Kestrel combinator), which you presently have to define yourself:

```
implicit class Tapper[A](val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def tap[B](f: A => B): A = { f(a); a }
  def taps[B](fs: A => B*): A = { fs.map(_(a)); a }
}
```

It works like so:

```
scala> "salmon".taps(
     |       println,
     |       println
     |     )
salmon
salmon
res2: String = salmon
```

Note also

```
val myFavoriteObject = {
  val x = new Obj
  x.setA("a")
}
```

will allow you to use a short name to do all the setting while assigning to a more meaningful name for longer-term use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implicit converter from/to a wrapper class that allows chaining.

Something like:

```
case class ObjWrapper(o: Obj) {
  def setA(a: String) = { o.setA(a); this }
  def setB(b: String) = { o.setB(b); this }
  def setC(c: String) = { o.setC(c); this }
}
implicit def wrapped2Obj(ow: ObjWrapper): Obj = ow.o

ObjWrapper(myObj).setA("a").setB("b").setC("c")
```

Actually you don't even need the implicit converter since those method have been called on `myObj`.

Comment: Simply importing ObjWrapper._ would be better, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Scalaxy/Beans](https://github.com/ochafik/Scalaxy/tree/master/Beans). Note however that it's using macros, so it should be considered experimental.